# `syntax error: unexpected end of file` report after carefully being checked

Tags: shell

I encounter `syntax error: unexpected end of file` during  running the following program.

```
    #! /bin/bash
    # Program to output a system information

    TITLE="System Information Report For $HOSTNAME"
    CURRENT_TIME="$(date +"%x %r %Z")"
    TIMESTAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

    report_uptime () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>System Uptime</h2>
            <pre>$(uptime)</pre>
            _EOF_
        return
    }

    report_disk_space () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>Disk Space Utilization</h2>
            <pre>$(df -h)</pre>
            _EOF_
        return
    }

    report_home_space () {
        cat <<- _EOF_
            <h2>Home Space Utilization</h2>
            <pre>$(du -sh ~/home/*)</pre>
            _EOF_
        return
    }

    cat << _EOF_
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
                <h1>$TITLE</h1>
                <p>$TIMESTAMP</p>
                $(report_uptime)
                $(report_disk_space)
                $(report_home_space)
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
    _EOF_
```

I debug it in separate units, there's no bugs from `cat << _EOF` to the end

```
    me at me in ~/desktop
    $ cat << _EOF_
    → <HTML>
    →     <HEAD>
    →         <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
    →     </HEAD>
    →     <BODY>
    →             <h1>$TITLE</h1>
    →             <p>$TIMESTAMP</p>
    →             $(report_uptime)
    →             $(report_disk_space)
    →             $(report_home_space)
    →     </BODY>
    → </HTML>
    → _EOF_
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
            <TITLE>System Information Report For Max-2018.local</TITLE>
        </HEAD>
        <BODY>
                <h1>System Information Report For Max-2018.local</h1>
                <p>Generated 04/01/2018 02:46:34 PM CST, by me</p>



        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

Furthermore, there's also no bugs if I eliminate all the commands in shell functions.

What's the bug it might be?

Comment: Are you sure that those `_EOF_` where used to delimit `<<- _EOF_` heredocs are preceded by one and only one TAB character? (no space?). does `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]{2,}_EOF_/l'` return something?

Comment: Assuming all here-documents are indented by real tabs, I can see no issues with this script, apart from trying to access `~/home/*` (did you mean `/home/*`?). If a here-document is delimited by the end of the file, you will get a warning saying "here-document at line NN delimited by end-of-file...".  I'm also assuming that the extra indentation of _all_ code is a formatting error on this site and not in your script.

Comment: ` sed -n '/^[[:space:]]{2,}_EOF_/l`
it return nothing.

Comment: Is the script a DOS text file, or does it contain carriage returns on some lines?

Comment: @Tool sorry my bad. It should have been `\{2,\}` instead of `{2,}`. More generally, `sed -n l` to see invisible characters.

Comment: ty, I try `sed -n "/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}_EOF_/l"` on the command line and also append to the end of script.  It still return nothing. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: it's a shell script file,I checked there's no carriage. @Kusalananda

Comment: Well, if I copy and paste the script from your question, remove the extra indentation and replace the indentation for the here-documents with tabs, it _works_.

Comment: @Tool, I meant to run `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}_EOF_/l'` on the content of your script to identify the lines that don't have only a TAB character before `_EOF_`. As in `sed -n '/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}_EOF_/l' < your-script`. The `l` `sed` command should show TABs as `\t`. If you see spaces instead or in addition before the `_EOF_` delimiter, that's where your problem is.

Comment: $ sed -n '/^[[:space:]]\{2,\}_EOF_/l' < /Users/gaowei/bin/sys_info_page
        _EOF_$
        _EOF_$
        _EOF_$
@StéphaneChazelas

Comment: there's eight spaces and two tabs before `_EOF_$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `<<- EOF` operator, the `EOF` delimiter has to be preceded by TABs **only** (or be at the start of the line), not spaces. A line that consists of `<space>EOF` or `<space><TAB>EOF` is not seen as delimiter.

In:

```
... <<- EOF
<TAB>line1
<TAB>line2\
<TAB>continued
<TAB>line3
<TAB>EOF
```

The leading TABs (above represented as `<TAB>`) are removed (except for the logical `line2` line continued on the next physical lines, except in old versions of `zsh` before it was fixed) before the `EOF` is looked for.

So here, you'd need to remove all the space characters before the `_EOF_` delimiter. Or better, avoid that `<<-` altogether and use put the `_EOF_` at the beginning of the line (making sure it's not *followed* by blanks). Personally, I don't like the idea of a language where the syntax depends on the amount of spaces, that's the main thing I dislike about `python` as well.

Comment: ty very much. I add extension `.sh`, vscode colored visually the problem.